# VBA Powerpoint to delete a TextBox

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

I want to delete three TextBox that are in the first slide. I wrote this code but it doesn't work!!
This is my code:

```
Sub deleteTextBox()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oShp1 As Shape
Dim oShp2 As Shape
Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
For Each oShp In osld.Shapes
If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
If oShp.Left = 20 And oShp.Top = 150 Then
oShp.Delete
End If
End If
Next oShp
For Each oShp1 In osld.Shapes
If oShp1.HasTextFrame Then
If oShp1.Left = 20 And oShp1.Top = 200 Then
oShp1.Delete
End If
End If
Next oShp1
For Each oShp2 In osld.Shapes
If oShp2.HasTextFrame Then
If oShp2.Left = 35 And oShp2.Top = 490 Then
oShp2.Delete
End If
End If
Next oShp2
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are your shapes positioned EXACTLY as per the values in you code. You can check by selecting them in turn and typing the following in the immediate window:

```
?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left

?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top
```

Also, you can optimise the code by looping through the shapes once and evaluating all 3 positioning conditions only once on each shape.

Comment: i find the solution by looping the shape. Thanks Jamie